# Binding JSON to kendo grid JavaScript

Tags: json, binding, grid, kendo-ui

Help me fix this code that was runing perfect two days ago. I don't have idea what i've chanched, but now, the grid is just empty, can you get me some help? Please.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
       sortable: true,
       groupable: true,
       scrollable: true,
       height: "300px",
       pageable: {
         pageSizes: 9
                 },
       dataSource: {
         transport: {
             read: {
                url: "http://localhost/pharmacypoints/api/Productos/getSinFiltro",
                    dataType: "Json"
                              }
             }
                },
    Columns:  [
              { field: "Codigo",
                tittle: "Codigo"
              }, 
      { field: "Descripcion", 
        tittle: "Descripcion" 
      }, 
      { field: "Familia", 
        tittle: "Familia"
      }, 
      { field: "Laboratorio",
        title: "Laboratorio"
      }, 
      { field: "Clasificacion",
        tittle: "Clasificacion"
      }]

                        });
```

The database result is like this:

```
[{"Codigo":"6140","Producto":"CIPROXINA FA 200ML 400MG","Familia":"ANTIBIOTICO 10","Clasificacion":"CONTROLADOS","Laboratorio":"BAYER DE MEXICO, SA DE CV"}, and more objects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two minor problems:

1. `Columns` must be lower case.
2. It is `title` and not `tittle`.

Try this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    sortable  : true,
    groupable : true,
    scrollable: true,
    height    : "300px",
    pageable  : {
        pageSizes: 9
    },
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url     : "http://localhost/pharmacypoints/api/Productos/getSinFiltro",
                dataType: "Json"
            }
        }
    },
    columns   : [
        { field: "Codigo", title: "Codigo" },
        { field: "Descripcion", title: "Descripcion" },
        { field: "Familia", title: "Familia" },
        { field: "Laboratorio", title: "Laboratorio" },
        { field: "Clasificacion", title: "Clasificacion" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! OnaBai,

However i found out those mistakes, my real problem was in the php file, but thanks for your response anyway. I'm new in this site, i don't know if i can give you a star or stuf...

Comment: So, my grid is working fine now, but there's a little issue, let me explain myself, i'm building a site where a user cans search for stuff, so there are 3 opcions: by descripcion, by code, or show them all, so i change the grid's datasource by every opcion, that's running fine now but the grid needs always two clicks to show new results. Is there any property wich i could use to fix it?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you share some code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing what you have and what is the problem?

Comment: Does the grid always have the same structure (same columns) and the question is the filtering, sorting, grouping condition?

Comment: you give a code and click the search button, the grid changes to show products with the given code tha's ok, then you give a diferent code or even the same code and click the search button, the grid now should call again the method but nothing happens, you click again the button and it finally works , but this loop begins again

Comment: Doesn't make sense! Did you check if the lost call sends something to the server and if so, what does it send? Do you create a new grid for each call or invoke dataSource filter/group/sort for getting the new data? I would need to take a look into the code to understand what it happens, is that possible?

Comment: that's the problem, it doesn't make sense.
I bind a new dataSource to the grid for each event. thank you so much but let me check all by myself, i might fix it sooner if i where looking into the code instead of surfing in the web.

Comment: Thanks but there's a lot of files involved, i appreciate your help and i'm making you know when i figure out what happens here